# Using mediawiki API to display a wikipedia page as-is

Tags: javascript, ajax, dom, mediawiki-api

I would like to use the API to display a wikipedia page as-is on my website.
I found [this API](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Styling_content) which could help but the documentation is limited and I can't figure much on how to use it.
In the user guide they reference a toy wiki browser called [miniwiki](https://jsfiddle.net/cscottnet/ceshcL3u/presentation/), I used that as a base for the following code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<!-- testing purpose file, used for trying to print a correctly formatted wikipedia page -->


<html>
    <head>  <!-- Tout ce qui est pas dans le contenu -->
        <title> game setup </title> <!-- Titre de l'onglet -->

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"> </script>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//en.wikipedia.org/w/load.php?modules=mediawiki.legacy.commonPrint,shared|mediawiki.skinning.elements|mediawiki.skinning.content|mediawiki.skinning.interface|skins.vector.styles|site|mediawiki.skinning.content.parsoid|ext.cite.style&amp;only=styles&amp;skin=vector"/>

    </head>

    <body style="background-color:white;">

        <h1 id="wiki-title">MiniWiki</h1>

        <div id="content"></div>

        <script>
            var contentElem = document.getElementById('content');
            var stylesheetElem = document.getElementById('style');
            var titleElem = document.getElementById('wiki-title');
            var url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org:443/api/rest_v1/page/html/Ancient_Egypt';

            $.ajax(url).then(function (data) {
                var $content = $(contentElem).empty();
                // $(stylesheetElem).remove();

                var doc = (new DOMParser()).parseFromString(data, 'text/html');

                // stylesheetElem = doc.querySelector('head link[rel="stylesheet"]');
                $('head').append(stylesheetElem);

                $(titleElem).text(doc.title.replace(/^User:Cscott\//, '').replace(/_/g, ' '));

                Array.from(doc.body.attributes).forEach(function (attr) {
                    $content.attr(attr.name, attr.value);
                });
                $content.append(Array.from(doc.body.children));  
            });       
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

As you can see if you try it, it returns some 404 errors, the page display some elements correctly, and some not at all. The same issues are present on the Miniwiki, so I wonder how to correct them.

Answer (score 1):

So am I correct to assume you want to display the page exactly as Wikipedia is showing it ? Currently you request that single page, same as https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ancient_Egypt?action=render. Perhaps use an iFrame with the url I mentioned? Would that solve the problem ?

---

So as an addition to my comment, you could just grab the stylesheet from the url with Ajax. It's already in your code.
For me this works like a charm :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<!-- testing purpose file, used for trying to print a correctly formatted wikipedia page -->

<html>
<head>  <!-- Tout ce qui est pas dans le contenu -->
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title> game setup </title> <!-- Titre de l'onglet -->
    <base href="//en.wikipedia.org" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"> </script>

</head>

<body style="background-color:white;">

<h1 id="wiki-title">MiniWiki</h1>

<div id="content"></div>

<script>
    var contentElem = document.getElementById('content');
    var titleElem = document.getElementById('wiki-title');
    var url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org:443/api/rest_v1/page/html/Ancient_Egypt';

    $.ajax(url).then(function (data) {
        var $content = $(contentElem).empty();
        // $(stylesheetElem).remove();

        var doc = (new DOMParser()).parseFromString(data, 'text/html');

        var stylesheetElem = doc.querySelector('head link[rel="stylesheet"]');
        $('head').append(stylesheetElem);

        $(titleElem).text(doc.title.replace(/^User:Cscott\//, '').replace(/_/g, ' '));

        Array.from(doc.body.attributes).forEach(function (attr) {
            $content.attr(attr.name, attr.value);
        });
        $content.append(Array.from(doc.body.children));
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are correct. However, the iframe solution is not good for me because I want to be able to interact with the content of the page such as hyperlinks clicks, and because of the cross domain policy I can't do that using an iframe.

Comment: Allright.. Then the miniwiki code ain't half bad. 
Go the the api link in the browser (https://en.wikipedia.org:443/api/rest_v1/page/html/Ancient_Egypt), view source, search for "stylesheet" and you will find a different stylesheet then what you have used in your code.. I found this :

//en.wikipedia.org/w/load.php?lang=en&amp;modules=mediawiki.skinning.content.parsoid%7Cmediawiki.skinning.interface%7Csite.styles%7Cext.timeline.styles%7Cext.wikihiero%7Cmediawiki.page.gallery.styles%7Cext.cite.style%7Cext.cite.styles&amp;only=styles&amp;skin=vector


Add that and it looks good

Comment: It does looks better thank you ! I still have some formatting issues though, some pictures are not in the good sections.